# Conditionally rendering cell data based on accessor value

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Just started using [react-table](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table), trying to figure out how to conditionally render something based on the accessor value. I get back some data from an api call and use one of the values for the accessor.

```
{
   Header: "Action",
   id: "startTime",
   accessor: "attributes.startTime"
}
```

So I have a column with header `"Action"`, here I want to conditionally render a button if the accessor value `attrbiutes.startTime === null` or something along those lines.

Rendering of the UI occurs in a different file so I also need to access it there for handling button `onClick`

I have a codesandbox here with a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-executions-6gjy1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom cell renderer

```js
const columns = [

  {
     Header: "Action",
     id: "startTime",
     accessor: "attributes.startTime",
     Cell: props => {
        return props.value === null ? <button>Click Me </button> : props.value;
     }
  }
];
```

Comment: Thanks, couldn't seem to find this in the docs. What exactly does `props.value` represent here?

Comment: `props.value` presents value eztracted by accessor key e.g. in this case `attributes.startTime`